# javax.bluetooth package

Tags: java, bluetooth

i am not able to find javax.bluetooth class files on net. can anyone suggest me websites

Comment: it comes with jsr082  check http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr082/javax/bluetooth/package-summary.html

Comment: Note that JSR-82 is only for J2ME: there's no official bluetooth library for Java SE (but there are third-party libraries).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking for a JSR-82 (javax.bluetooth) implementation for J2SE.

[Bluecove](http://bluecove.org/) is an open-source JSR-82 implementation.

[Avetana](http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/jsr82.eng.xml) is a commercial JSR-82 implementation.